# Godot - GDScript: set_texture not working

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I am currently creating my first godot project, a snake clone and just don't understand why this isn't working as it is supposed to. I try to change the texture of my snake sprite in code with sprite.set_texture(). Changing the texture with sprite.set_texture(sprite.texture2) does work while sprite.set_texture(sprite.texture) doesn't work. I don't get any error, the texture just doesn't change. texture is the default texture of the sprite and texture2 is also a Texture2D and added with @export.
This is my code:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@onready var sprite = $Sprite

const MOVESPEED = 200


func _ready():
    sprite.global_position = Vector2(get_viewport().size / 2)
    velocity = MOVESPEED * Vector2.RIGHT


func _process(_delta):
    var current_direction = Vector2(velocity.x, velocity.y).normalized()
    current_direction = get_movement_direction(current_direction)
    if current_direction != Vector2.ZERO:
        velocity = current_direction * MOVESPEED
    move_and_slide()


func get_movement_direction(current_direction):
    
    var x_movement = Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
    var y_movement = Input.get_action_strength("move_down") - Input.get_action_strength("move_up")
    
    
    if x_movement != 0:
        if x_movement == 1:
            current_direction = Vector2.RIGHT
            sprite.set_texture(sprite.texture)
            sprite.flip_h = false
        else:
            current_direction = Vector2.LEFT
            sprite.set_texture(sprite.texture)
            sprite.flip_h = true
    elif y_movement != 0:
        if y_movement == 1:
            current_direction = Vector2.DOWN
            sprite.set_texture(sprite.texture2)
            sprite.flip_v = true
        else:
            current_direction = Vector2.UP
            sprite.set_texture(sprite.texture2)
            sprite.flip_v = false
    
    return current_direction
```

I already verified that both textures do exist. I really have no clue what else I can check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the mistake:

> texture is the default texture

No, it isn't.

---

The `texture` property is not the default texture. The `texture` property is the **current** texture.

In fact, when you do:

```
sprite.set_texture(sprite.texture)
```

It is the same as doing:

```
sprite.texture = sprite.texture
```

Which I hope is clear enough to understand why it does nothing.